# Firebase Database relationship issue - storing selected items for users

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, real-time

So I am definitely a firebase and just generally a noSql noob at this point.  here is my issue.

I have a set of data like so

```
-items
 --id1
   theData
 --id2
   theData
 --id3
   theData
 --id4
   theData
```

I have users that will select a subset of this data.  Example User A and User B right now.

```
-itemSelected
 ---UserA
    ---Id1  (different than item key)
       theData from items id1 (with items id1 key included so I can reference)
    ---Id2  (different than item key)
       theData from items id3 (with items id3 key included so I can  reference)
  ---UserB
    ---Id1 (different than item key)
       theData from items id1 (with items id1 key included so I can reference)
    ---Id2 (different than item key)
       theData from items id4 (with items id4 key included so I can reference)
```

Having a more structure normalized SQL background I feel I am going about this wrong.  As I develop Im seeing where if I change the items data, then I will have bad data in my user data documents.  Im so far along in my project and its not that big a project Id like to finish it with firebase realtime db and id like to get my head around this noSql.  so what am i missing or doing wrong on how this should be setup.  Or should I just be switching to Firestore and if so how does that solve my problem.

FYI - The reason I need the reference is because there are times where these 2 pieces of data will need to be compared so I can properly display tables.  I think keys are the natural way to compare data.  Again I could be very SQL minded there.

Hoping there's some noSql or firebase specialists out there to provide some solutions.  Thanks!

***Update***

Based on responder Bryan Massoth I think this is purposed new structure.

```
-items
 --id1
   theData
 --id2
   theData
 --id3
   theData
 --id4
   theData
```

I have users that will select a subset of this data but instead of storing copies of the data, just store key value of items ids and boolean true for selected. Example User A and User B right now.

```
-itemSelected
 ---UserA
    ---Id1  (different than item key)
       id1KeyFromItems: "True"
    ---Id2  (different than item key)
       id3KeyFromItems: "True"
  ---UserB
    ---Id1 (different than item key)
       id1KeyFromItems: "True"
    ---Id2 (different than item key)
       id4KeyFromItems: "True"
```

So one last issue potentially i see is I am currently displaying the data the user selected in another table which is why I originally had written all the subselected data to userA or UserB's profile in firebase. So i could easily just subscribe to it and display it from there.  If I go the boolean route, how can i display only the data from items that User A selected if Im only storing the keys?

Comment: There's a lot of ambiguity in the question making it hard to provide direction. 1) *users that will select a subset of this data* - does that mean you are querying for the data? or from a list? some other mechanic 2) *these 2 pieces of data will need to be compared* what two pieces? 3) *I have users that will select a subset of this data* what subset? How will it be selected? Data duplication is common in NoSQL; however, if that data may change, keeping a reference to the data is can be the best path. However, that depends on what you want to get out of Firebase. Clarification is needed!

Comment: Im trying to keep this as boiled down as possible but i I will try answer your questions to clarify.  1)It means that I have a list (a table) in my app of Items.  Users select not all items but some of the items.  These items become a part of their profile essentially. 2.) when the user revisits, that list (the table of itens) will render with selects.  It compares what they already have and checks those boxes for them so they dont have to reselect what they already have.  So i need the key in both places to do the this.

Comment: 3,)They are using a table with select checkbox and a submit.  It creates and updates to Firebase RT DB.

Comment: 4.)I do need to display the data the User B selected (sub selected data from items) in either a table or potentially some material paper components inidividually.  I will add that above.  That does seem important since I don't know if the if just storing the user selected from from items with boolean will allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have gone through this.  Bryan got me part of the way there so I upvoted his response but Im posting the full answer here so others may benefit.  I tried to keep the initial question as boiled down as I could but I realize that is difficult and this is maybe not the best forum but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else and I had specific use case which I can share more now with code.

Use case to summize.  I have Items stored in firebase. User is going to select from items.  I need to store what they select but keep the data as maintainable as possible.  Bryan suggested store only the key which is fine.  But I was displaying what the user selected in a div in the UI so essentially if I didn't store the data in there profile I would need to filter on original items data (I realized this after bryan's post) based off of the stored keys in my users profile.

Im a React app so I wired up Reselect and used Selectors to load the 2 data parts where I had matches with filters and wired them through redux in the components.

If your new to selectors, this video was pretty helpful for me and getting this solution wired up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCQ0ZSr-a2o

Relevant code for selector here.  Basically your taking the items list and the userSelectedItems list (which is just the keys/ids) and comparing them.  If they are same, then filter will eval true for new filtered list.

Here is my selector stuff.

```
export function getUser(state) {
   return state.User;
 }

export function getUserItemsList(state) {
  return getTeam(state).list;
 }


export function getItemsList(state) {
 return state.Items.list
}

export function getUserItemsFilter(userItems, items) {

  const selectedItems = items.filter(
    item => userItems.some(userItem => userItem.itemKey === item.key));
   return selectedItems
 }

 export const ItemSelector = createSelector(
  getUserItemsList,  //pick off piece of state
  getItemsList,  //pick off piece of state
  getUserItemsFilter //last argument that runs for Item Selector, do processing here
 );
```

Back in the component you import selector you created and wire it to your mapStateToProps like so.

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
   itemsSelected: ItemSelector(state),
   }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = Object.assign(
  {},
  userActions,
);

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserPage));
```

Now ItemsSelected will be mapped state to your React component.  It's the filtered Items array with only the values entries that have the same key as the ones you stored in the users profile.

This really solves my original issue of keeping my data more easily maintainable in Firebase since all the data is in items, not duplicated in the users profiles.  Thank you Immutable and Reselect in React.  They are built for this stuff.  Hoping this helps someone else.  Realize this was a bit broad for stack at first, hopefully the code helps refine the use case and make it valuable for others now.

And for one last time.  My data looks like this in firebase now.

Items

```
-items
 --id1
   theData
 --id2
   theData
 --id3
   theData
 --id4
   theData
```

UserProfile

```
-itemSelected
 ---UserA
    ---Id1  (different than item key)
       "id": "id1KeyFromItems"
    ---Id2  (different than item key)
       "id": "id3KeyFromItems"
  ---UserB
    ---Id1 (different than item key)
       "id": "id1KeyFromItems"
    ---Id2 (different than item key)
       "id": "id4KeyFromItems"
```

My high level DB functions always create new unique keys in firebase.  I didn't want to change that just for this solution.  This works and keeps everything running  the same for CRUD in my app.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the structure depends on exactly how you will be using the data. I'd say that most of your structure is correct. The only difference I would make would be to not duplicate the data under `itemSelected/{userId}`. Just have the actual `itemId` set to `true` if it is selected.

```
-itemSelected
  -UserA
    -Id1 (same as items Id1): true
    -Id2 (same as items Id2): true
```

This would add extra loads, but those can be hidden with a good UI/UX design. This would allow a search for users that have a specific item selected. It would also ensure that the data is not bad.

With regards to the "subset" comment about the data stored in `itemSelected`: if you are referring to a specific item's data being a subset of the data stored for that item in the `items` table and that is designed for security (i.e. some data in the `items` section should not be seen by the user), then I'd suggest leaving everything the same but just creating a Firebase Function to keep records "eventually" consistent.

Comment: Ahh, so dont store the data, just store that the id was selected with a boolean.  Let me look at that because firebase puts new Id's everywhere.  I will have to look at how that structure might shake out a minute.  I will post an update on what I think your mean.  Give me a minute.

Comment: -UserA
    -Id1 (same as items Id1)  <--- this is just data right, not the key.  firebase will put key between UserA and Id1( same as items id1) I believe.

Comment: Can you take a take a look at the updated structure.  in my above post.  its making sense. I just want to make sure that is what you mean.  Because there is still going to be another id in there that is for the boolean.

Comment: i need the key of what was selected so when the user brings up a table of items, it renders what they have already selected before.  I think what you are suggesting by just storing the items key and boolean will still give me the keys i need to compare against the items array when i render the table to set the selects

Comment: @Puerto do you need the extra key in your examples? Try to keep just the item keys under the user. If you nest them under other "unknown" keys (keys that you might not know at the time of querying) then you won't be able to do some of the queries I mentioned above.

Comment: I will look into that.  right now my high level db function does that for all new data, it creates a key.

Comment: usually when linking/referencing data, you should use the IDs already created. This allows you to query based on those IDs. If you create new ones to wrap around the originals, then you need both IDs to do the same query and you add extra unnecessary data.

Comment: But your purposing I store the items Id as the key and true would be the value in UserA.  Your not suggesting I take the id from Items and create a duplicate ID in  UserA right? Are you?